# using React component library without @types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm developing React with TypeScript

What I want to do is to use React component library without @types definition.

I'd like to use this library
https://github.com/react-component/calendar

In my React code, I wrote as below

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Calendar from 'rc-calendar';

ReactDOM.render(<Calendar />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

but I get error:

```
ERROR in ./index.tsx
(4,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rc-calendar'.
```

I'm guessing this is because there is no type definition but the library above seems not have type definition file for typescript.
How could I use such library with TypeScript?

Comment: Javascript in Typescript without definition is perfectly legal. Are you certain you have this library in your `node_modules` and it is included in webpack (if you use it)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In TypeScript 2.1, unless you're using `--noImplicitAny`, you will be able to just use this library without declaration files (provided that it's installed).

But since TS 2.1 isn't out yet, what you can do is create a file called `externals.d.ts` with the following content:

```
declare module "rc-calendar";
```

That basically tells TypeScript "hey, this thing exists, stop bugging me, and I want to use it however I want."

You can also give it a slightly better shape.

```
declare module "rc-calendar" {
    declare var calendar: any;
    export default calendar;
}
```

Now this thing can only be imported as a default import.

You can continue fleshing this thing out until it is sufficiently detailed.

Comment: Thanks, I could successfully compiled it

Comment: I understand that is an old answer but this seems like a hack. As importing the component like this does not bring in its prop types. So the props need to be hand crafted for it, without type checking.